# "PyCharm can't check if the following file been updated" when doing makemigrations/migrate

Tags: django, pycharm, manage.py, makemigrations

When I use PyCharm's manage.py terminal to do a **makemigrations** or **migrate** I have the following warning message:

`PyCharm can't check if the following file been updated: [filepath]`

for a hundred of files located inside my **webpack** and **babel-preset-es2015** folders, within my **static/node_modules** folder

The command is executed properly, but I would like to get rid of these hundreds of red warnings in the terminal. Especially since I think the migrations takes longer to be executed since I have those.

Can I somehow tell PyCharm to stop checking my **node_modules** or even **static** folders?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particularly brilliant solution but you can just comment out the line in _jb_utils.py, if you can find it. For me on OS X it was here:

`~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/172.4343.24/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_utils.py`

Obviously you will have to redo this every time you update PyCharm though.